# How to change gutter in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I need to know, how can I change the gutter in bootstrap, but only for the gallery section, not for all layout.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, if you are able, I'd set a body class of "gallery" or, if that's not possible, wrap your gallery in a section/div with a unique identifier.

Let's say you called it "my-gallery". Then you can override the bootstrap styles like this:

**html**

```
<div class="my-galery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.my-gallery .col-xs-12 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;  // adjust this value
    padding-right: 15px; // adjust this value
}
```

Just change `.col-xs-12` to whatever grid you are using. `.col-md-4` (for example)

Comment: I don't need left and right padding i just need the thumbails to be W: 546px and H:185px and spacing between 8px.

Comment: The padding is what adjusts the width of your gutters.

Comment: But how can i set Width and Height.

Comment: My page containers is 1100px, gallery is 2 columns by 5 rows. gallery thumbnails is 546px, so 546+546px=1 092px, which means i need 8px gutter. In css i need to use padding left and right for 4px. But now how can i extend gallery to the edge of container, because of margins and how to receive thumbnail height of 185px, should i use max-height 185px; PLEASE  help me.